# Linux standard Headers (sys/type.h) uses not defined types under C++

Tags: c++, linux, typedef

I am currently trying to compile a C++ program. (Namely Higan)
I tried compiling it, but the standard headers somehow doesn't work. I am using a 64-bit Arch Linux, which is up-to-date. (`pacman -Syu` does nothing)

```
GCC (and headers) Version: 4.9.2
Linux Kernel (and headers) Version: 3.19.2-1-ARCH
```

I don't know what triggers the error, but I know, that ideone has the same issue on at least 2 files (one file is http://ideone.com/f8dO4i)

I am leaving an error log here, hoping someone could understand my problem.

```
In file included from /usr/include/libio.h:31:0,
             from /usr/include/stdio.h:74,
             from ./nall/platform.hpp:26,
             from ./emulator/emulator.hpp:20,
             from target-higan/higan.hpp:1,
             from target-higan/higan.cpp:1:
/usr/include/_G_config.h:22:3: Error: »__off_t« does not name a type
   __off_t __pos;
/usr/include/_G_config.h:27:3: Error: »__off64_t« does not name a type
   __off64_t __pos;
```

(Full log: http://hastebin.com/raw/oqezigewic)

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `~/higan_v094-source $ make` works completely fine on my Arch x64.

Comment: `__off_t` comes from `bits/types.h` which is included at the beginning of `_G_config.h` here. I suggest you compile with -E and look at that region of the output for anything suspicious.